# How to log internet certificate users in IBM Domino server?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

I know authenticated internet certificate users are logged.  I would like to log the internet certificate users (that are NOT in Address Book).  Currently these users appear as Anonymous in the log.  I want to have the user's common name associated with the certificate to appear in the log.  I know the CGI variable "HTTPS_CLIENT_CERT_COMMON_NAME" will capture this.
Any ideas would be appreciated.

V/R,

Kev

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to put code in your applications to do this, or write a [DSAPI plugin](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/tools/c/5.0.3/api503ug.nsf/85255d56004d2bfd85255b1800631684/aad371dc1de6cad58525687b0054da41?OpenDocument) if you want it done at the server level.

If you're looking for a solution that doesn't involve writing custom code, that's really a question for ServerFault rather than StackOverflow - but I suspect that there's no solution for that.

Comment: Thanks Richard,   Originally I tried to set the cookie header with certificate name but that was only good if cookies were allowed.  Just not familiar with DSAPI plugin but that may be the route I need to go.

Comment: DSAPI has a reputation of being very tricky to work with. I haven't done anything with it in more than ten years, so I don't know if it's gotten any easier. There's not a lot of info out there on the old Lotus forums, either, but there is some.